# Empty index.html after building my vite react project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vite, webdev.webserver

I tried deploying my app with Firebase Hosting, and it shows a blank page. It works normally when I run it locally. Also, when I try to open the index.html, it still shows a blank page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzIqJ.png)

I've tried creating a new Vite React project and built it without even touching the code, and still I encounter the same problem.

I just want to show the contents of website

Comment: Did you try firebase emulators (test production code locally)? Also please provide more context like your file structure, vite configuration, html/jsx entrypoints...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.